# undefined reference to '__atomic_*' in SCons but similar questions' solution won't work

Tags: c++, g++, scons, godot, stdatomic

I'm trying to build Godot with SCons. Everything was working fine until I've used `std::atomic` in my library my custom module uses (the library is working fine with a Qt application I've created to test it). Then this error happened:

```
[100%] Linking Program        ==> bin/godot.x11.tools.64
/usr/bin/ld: /home/sms/Code/_BUILDS/build-PyWally-Desktop-Release/libPyWally.so: undefined reference to `__atomic_store_16'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/sms/Code/_BUILDS/build-PyWally-Desktop-Release/libPyWally.so: undefined reference to `__atomic_load_16'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
scons: *** [bin/godot.x11.tools.64] Error 1
scons: building terminated because of errors.
```

I was googling around and found out about atomic/architecture problems, so I've added `-march=native`, `-mtune=native` and `-latomic` because I have modern x64 PC/system and it shoudn't be an issue... so my SCsub looks like this (`wallycontroller` being my custom module, and `pywally` - my library):

```
Import('env')

sources = [
    "wallycontroller.cpp",
    "wallycontroller.cpp",
    "register_types.cpp"
]

env.Append(CPPPATH=["/usr/include/python3.10"])
env.Append(LIBS=['python3.10'])
env.Append(CCFLAGS=['-march=native', '-mtune=native', '-latomic'])

env.Append(CPPPATH=["#bin/../../PyWallie"])
env.Append(LIBPATH=["#bin/../../../_BUILDS/build-PyWally-Desktop-Release"])
env.Append(LIBS=['PyWally'])

envw = env.Clone()
envw.Append(CCFLAGS=['-O2'])

if ARGUMENTS.get('wallycontroller_shared', 'no') == 'yes':
    envw.Append(CCFLAGS=['-fPIC'])
    envw['LIBS'] = []
    envw.Append(LIBS=['python3.10'])
    envw.Append(LIBS=['PyWally'])
    shared_lib = envw.SharedLibrary(target='#bin/../../godot_modules/wallycontroller', source=sources)
    shared_lib_shim = shared_lib[0].name.rsplit('.', 1)[0]
    env.Append(LIBS=[shared_lib_shim])
    env.Append(LIBPATH=['#bin'])
else:
    envw.add_source_files(env.modules_sources, sources)
```

And these are my SCons arguments on build:

```
platform = "x11"
tools = "yes"
target = "debug"
bits = 64
custom_modules = "../godot_modules"
use_lto = "yes"
walliecontroller_shared = "yes"
udev = "no"
```

Any issue wasn't happening for this configuration until I've add `std::atomic` but it's really convenient and I wouldn't want to remove it... any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Which platform? Which compiler (gcc,clang,other)? Which compiler version?  Have you tried adding 'atomic' to your list of libraries you link against? (or googled missing symbol __atomic_store_16?)

Comment: @bdbaddog Fedora x86_64, GCC 11.3.1. About proposed solutions, like I've said in the post and as u can see in my SCsub, I'm adding -latomic, -march=native and -mtune=native which were the solutions I've googled for __atomic_store_16 :( libatomic.so is in my /usr/lib

Comment: add 'atomic' to LIBS, not CCFLAGS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To help you debug, try temporarily commenting out the setting of `LINKCOMSTR` (should be in `methods.py`) so that SCons can show you the whole link line - normally Godot tries to be "helpful" and emit shorter messages, but it doesn't help when you're getting something like a link failure.  You'll *probably* notice that it's not linking with libatomic after all.  In SCons, you actually need to add that library to `LIBS` (without the `-l`) to pass it to the linker.

---

A separate question is why it thinks it need it - I'm presuming the architecture you're building on has atomic support?

With optimization disabled, GCC often calls helper functions for atomic operations instead of inlining.

For x86-64, GCC7 and later [always calls a helper function](https://gcc.gnu.org/legacy-ml/gcc-patches/2017-01/msg02344.html) for 16-byte atomics, instead of inlining `lock cmpxchg16b`.  (And now so it can use `movaps` on CPUs with AVX where that guarantees atomicity of 16-byte pure-load and pure-store.)  So `gcc -latomic` is always necessary when compiling for x86-64, if you use 16-byte atomic objects.

Comment: Well, it worked... this library was tested on this PC, just on a Qt app, not buiild with SCons... so I guess I have the support. Thanks!